# Duplicates and sorting

Tags: excel-formula, duplicates

[My table updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKIDv.png)
See if this picture of my table helps understand what I am trying to do. Thank you. B1 is where I am trying to return the column C count. I do have some duplicates in column B (as mentioned with previous table).

Comment: I am deleting my answer, please add to the question that the outputs will contain `#N/A` errors.

Comment: Wrap the formulas in Column C: `=IFERROR(...,0)` where `...` is your formula.  It will then return `0` instead of `#N/A`  Then you can use my formula.

Comment: Done and it returns a 0 it is not returning a 2 as I am looking for. I will screen shot the table again with the formula in view to ensure I have no errors.

Comment: B4 is where I am trying to get my return for CG's

Comment: Did I mess up on anything?

Comment: Use the if error on the source data C16:C32 not my formula.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: In the range C16:C32, you have formulas, that result in N/A, probably a VLOOKUP.  Wrap those formulas in IFERROR().: like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),0)`  This will change all the errors to 0.  IF you do not want 0 put `""` in place for 0.  Do the error checking and fix on the data source not on the downstream formulas.  You would change all the formulas to this, It will return the correct value or 0 if the formula results in an error.

Comment: =INDEX('NSA List'!$A$4:$L$459,MATCH(1,('NSA List'!$D$4:$D$459=B22)*('NSA List'!$J$4:$J$459="SPORT"),0),12) is the formula in C16:C32

Comment: Adding IFERROR worked. Here is the formula that worked: =IFERROR(INDEX('NSA List'!$A$4:$L$459,MATCH(1,('NSA List'!$D$4:$D$459=B16)*('NSA List'!$J$4:$J$459="SPORT"),0),12),"")

Comment: So you are using my formula?  I will undelete it so you can mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Here is the formula:{ =IFERROR(SUM(IF(C10:C166=0.5,1/COUNTIFS(B10:B166,B10:B166,C10:C166,0.5))),"")}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formulas to count the uniques:

```
=SUM(IF(B1:B8=0.5,1/COUNTIFS(A1:A8,A1:A8,B1:B8,0.5)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: How do I exclude #N/A's? The formula is not working.

Comment: Quick lesson, please include enough in your data set to include any issue like that.  It would help us not waste our time building something that does not work for your actual data.

Comment: The easiest way is to fix the formulas that are returning the numbers in the source list to deal with those errors.  Wrap those formulas in an `IFERROR()`